# iOS application is crashing for users after update released to appstore [complex case]

Tags: app-store-connect

I am experiencing a strange issue.

New app version was released to appstore, containing new variable stored in user defaults and some minor updates. technically, we are creating new variable, which is an array of values in user defaults, and appending some items in the array. For append, we are using values which were already in place in the previous version (e.g. user_id, device_id and one more string parameter, all 3 were received from backend on 1st registration).

It was (obviously) tested before release. Testing strategy:
A. We were building adhoc old version (say #1) and new version (say #2), installing v1 on the devices and updating it to v2 (by simply downloading new adhoc v2 and installing it on top of v1).

Then, we published v2 to appstore, and issued one more test:

B. We were building same adhoc old version (say #1) installing v1 on the devices and updating it from the appstore, by

B.1 in-app update functionality - following the link to appstore and
B.2 just downloading most recent version from appstore.

Both were fine and both are still fine. Works perfectly.

Now, users are reporting old appstore-installed v.1, updated from appstore to v.2, is crashing after update (almost immediately when it is started).

Only difference we can observe is that when tested, appstore version was installed over adhoc, and now it is appstore over appstore.

Was anybody ever facing the same issue? What is the difference in update process "adhoc -> appstore" versus "appstore -> appstore"? Could it be related to the fact that appstore update is cleaning up all the info from user defaults and thus we need to repeat the application reg process (get all the data again like in the first clean install)?

I still have no crash reports in hand, so I am asking for some advices which can help me to solve the issue faster.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

...looks like the issue is linked to GoogleUtilities: we have v7.2 in our current build, however previous build was of v7.4, and - as I found out recently, there is an issue related. TWIMC see https://github.com/google/GoogleUtilities/pull/37 for details.

It is still TBC now, we'll be checking in the next 1-2 days, and I will post some updates here. If indeed related to library version, then it has nothing to do with the app distribution (whatever if it is adhoc or appstore based).